# Can't Attach Data source from Access Database 2016

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hello i have a problem when i add data source from access database file and click test connection it show error Microsoft . ace.12.0 is not registered on local machine
but when i run my application all query working fine save/delete/update and also data grid view properly fetch all value 
but i cant attach my access database file into my data source

I have
Microsoft Office 2016 64bit
Access Database Engine 2016 64bit
windows 10 64bit but problem not solve

and my iism application pool setting set to 32 bit true

Comment: please help someone urgent needed

Comment: how are we expected to reproduce this problem?

Comment: plz help All things is perfect but still same problem

Comment: Aravi you don't understand how to use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved i have to change my office 2016 from 64bit to 32bit now working fine without access database engine